# ogr2ogr creates too many columns with LEFT JOIN

Tags: gdal, shapefile, sql, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I am creating a GeoPackage using several shapefiles using ogr2ogr (GDAL 2.2.4):

```sh
ogr2ogr -f GPKG /path/to/out.gpkg -append -nln out -a_srs EPSG:4326 /path/to/in1.shp
ogr2ogr -f GPKG /path/to/out.gpkg -append -nln out -a_srs EPSG:4326 /path/to/in2.shp
...
```

So far it does exactly what I want. All files are merged in a single GeoPackage file as long as all Shapefiles share the same column structure.

Now I would like to add columns based on a relation with another table, which can be done using a [JOIN from the SQL dialect](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#joins):

```sql
SELECT * FROM in LEFT JOIN '/path/to/other.dbf'.other ON in.a = other.a
```

I simply use the `-sql` option to pass the SQL query and voilà!

```sh
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM in LEFT JOIN '/path/to/other.dbf'.other ON in.a = other.a" -f GPKG /path/to/out.gpkg -append -nln out -a_srs EPSG:4326 /path/to/in.shp
```

It does what I asked, but it also adds unexpected columns.

Let’s say `in.shp` contains the following columns: `a` and `b`

And `other.dbf` contains the following columns: `a` and `c`

I would except to get columns: `a`, `b` and `c`

However I get columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `in.a`, `in.b`, `other.a` and `other.c`

(for clarity I did not mention the mandatory columns `geom` and `fid`)

I thought that `SELECT *` was a bit too inclusive, so I tried to select a limited set of columns:

```sql
SELECT a FROM in LEFT JOIN '/path/to/other.dbf'.other ON in.a = other.a
```

And I get the following columns: `a`, `in.a`, `in.b`, `other.a` and `other.c`

It looks like the in.* and other.* columns are always inserted as long as I perform a LEFT JOIN.

Is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: I feel that joining the .dbf file is actually leading to SQLite ATTACH DATABASE https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html. Then the original gpkg and attached dbf belong to different schemas. Try to import the dbf first into the gpkg as an attribute table and use JOIN between the tables which are now in the same database. Tell if it makes difference or not.

Comment: @user30184 that’s an interesting suggestion, however if I include both tables in separate steps, `ogr2ogr` does not see the former one. For example if I call `ogr2ogr -f GPKG temp.gpkg in.shp` then `ogr2ogr -f GPKG temp.gpkg other.dbf -append -sql ...` the latter operation does not see the table from the former operation (table `in`). Ditto if I insert in different order (import DBF first and then Shapefile)

Comment: I would try without using -sql in this step. Import .dbf file into temp.gpkg into a temporary table. Then it might be best to create a new table with something like `ogr2ogr -f gpkg -update temp.gpkg temp.gpkg -sql "select ....LEFT JOIN..ON temp_dbf.." -nln joined"`

Comment: @user30184 I already tried to import tables separately, but I didn’t think of `-update` back then. It seems to work very well, albeit significant additional steps of course. If you wish to write a proper answer I would gladly upvote it.

Comment: What if you write the answer yourself?

Comment: I can definitely do that (and I eventually will if you don’t) but credits wouldn’t go where it’s due.

Comment: You have done all the testing and if you do also the writing you have certainly deserved the credits.